# How to make a function in an activity that is available in all tab fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am building an app that uses three tab fragments and I want to create a function in one place that I can call from all three tabs. I would assume that I need to create the new function in the activity that contains the tabs, but I'm not sure how to declare it or how to call it from one of the tab fragments.

This is how i create my tabs in the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Search", "History", "Saved" };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Initialise the Database connection
        DBAdapter.init(this);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Setup tab bar
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        //Add the tabs to the action bar
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        //Tab Swipe change listener
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the function you need to call in the parent Activity and it must be a public method

and you can call that function like this:

```
((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).yourPublicMethod();
```